# Pyomo calling the value of a set

Tags: python, indexing, pyomo

Let us consider the following set:

```
m.sub_sit = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=[site],
    doc='site of sub problem')
```

in this case `m.sub_sit` is created by `create_model()` function with the argument `'Mid'`:

```
inst = create_model(site='Mid')
```

what I get by calling `inst.sub_sit.pprint()`:

In:

```
inst.sub_sit.pprint()
```

Out:

```
sub_sit : site of sub problem
    Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=1, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    ['Mid']
```

What I really want to output is `'Mid'`, so that I can index other objects with `'Mid'`, and then I can use it in my code.

e.g.:

In1: `PiZero`
In2: `PiZero[inst.sub_sit[1]]`
In3: `PiZero['Mid']`
Out1:

```
 sub_sit
 Mid   -1.0
 Name: sub_costs, dtype: float64
```

Out2: `-1.0`

Out3: `-1.0`

**Question: is there anyway to call this `'Mid'` string from `m.sub_sit` pyomo set object, better than what I suggest?**

btw `m.sub_sit.value` gives an output, almost what I needed: `{'Mid'}`

Comment: Why are you trying to index into a Pyomo Set using square brackets? If you want to index a variable by sub_sit you can do so with: m.PiZero = Var(m.sub_sit, initialize=-1)

Comment: it is a concrete model and PiZero is a dual variable which is not inside sub model, and is used for generating cuts for the master model...

Comment: @Engineero it was about pandas series because PiZero was pandas series object. TY for edit but also you are wrong.

Comment: You really need to give more context and show more of the model/code. Your question doesn't say anything about using Pandas objects. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do with sub_sit and PiZero.

Comment: question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `ordered=True` is added to `m.sub_sit`. Then `'Mid'` was calliable with `inst.sub_sit[1]`. It should be ordered set otherwise it generates an error, that you cannot call the first object of unordered set.

```
m.sub_sit = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=[site],
    ordered=True,
    doc='site of sub problem')
```

---

In:

```
inst.sub_sit[1]
```

Out:

```
'Mid'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never have to index into a Pyomo Set using square brackets. If you find yourself wanting to do this then you might want to rethink your motivation for using a Pyomo Set instead of a native Python list.

If your goal is to iterate through the values in the Pyomo Set and use those to index into Pandas objects then you can do something like:

```
for s in m.sub_sit:
    v = PiZero[s]
    # Do something with v
```

Alternatively you can cast the Pyomo Set to a list and work with the list instead:

```
s = list(m.sub_sit)
```

But again, if you're going to do this, do you really need the Pyomo Set?

If you want more examples of using Pandas and Pyomo together then take a look at [this](https://github.com/sandialabs/chama/blob/master/chama/optimize.py#L154) github repo for a sensor placement package. In particular you can see examples of creating Pyomo Sets using values from a Pandas DataFrame and also how to write constraints that use data in a DataFrame.

Comment: well it is a huge model and same model is used to create different models. Just one exception that the sub_sit is changing to an other string. And I don't need to use the for loop, since 'Mid' is the only element of it. Yes I could use a native python variable like: sub_sit = 'Mid' and then index it, but a drawback is I cannot reach sub_sit inside my constraint declerations, since the model given to the const_rules I can always get the value of m.sub_sit inside those const_rules.

Comment: here is an example:
`def sub_costs_rule(m):
    return (pyomo.summation(m.costs) <= m.eta_res[m.sub_sit[1]] + m.Lambda * m.omegazero)`

and yes I can always do `def sub_costs_rule(m, sub_sit)`, but now the `sub_cost_rule` has an other index, and it is breaking some of my functions. So better with first way.

Comment: Will sub_sit ever have more than one item? Another option is to attach your own data to a model e.g. `m.sub_sit = 'Mid'` or `m.sub_sit = ['Mid']`

Comment: You are right. One question though, do you think would it make a difference on computational speed if I declare it as a pyomo set, instead of `m.sub_sit = 'Mid'?`

Comment: Using a pyomo set will use more memory. I'm not sure if there is a significant difference in computational speed.

Comment: Hi Bethany. Is this still an issue? I'm currently debating whether I use Pyomo sets or simple lists to define certain constraints. Any updates on the memory/time efficiency of the alternatives?